# Netbeans bold text after Sierra update

Tags: netbeans, ide, multiple-monitors, macos-sierra

This isn't something that is holding me up, but its annoying.

In Netbeans (I was using 8.1, updated to 8.2--the problem exists in both), the bottom bar text appears in a bold font that does not render very nice at all. On my laptop monitor (Macbook Pro, retina) the font is still bold, but at least not so jagged looking. On either of my two external monitors (both 1920x1080) the text looks terrible. When I hover over the next, previous or select buttons the bold text goes away and they look fine.

This happens with font smoothing enabled or disabled. Any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcTSO.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure this out. Changing the IDE look and feel to Nimbus fixes it--sort of. I have to use the Nimbus Look and Feel, but its actually pretty nice looking.